# How to invoke windows theme in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes

Hi Folks I am trying to invoke the current theme of windows for my elements in WPF 3.5.

as the user change the window theme my application should also be changed according to the theme.

I am using styles.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a different look and feel based on the desktop theme by adding a resource dictionary to the Themes folder.  The desktop theme determine which resource dictionary is used.  Here is a list the resource dictionary file names and the desktop themes:

1. Classic.xaml – “Classic” Windows 9x/2000 look on Windows XP.
2. Luna.NormalColor.xaml – Default blue theme on Windows XP.
3. Luna.Homestead.xaml – Olive theme on Windows XP.
4. Luna.Metallic.xaml – Silver theme on Windows XP.
5. Royale.NormalColor.xaml – Default theme on Windows XP Media Center Edition.
6. Zune.NormalColor.xaml – Default theme on Windows XP Zune.
7. Aero.NormalColor.xaml – Default theme on Windows Vista
   ...

You can read details there (http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/07/31/using-themes-with-custom-controls.aspx)

Comment: I'm looking at a very similar problem here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859215/how-to-make-a-wpf-program-match-the-currently-selected-windows-theme) and I would greatly appreciate some elaboration. Is it the case that so long as the current system theme is added to the resource dictionary, it will be used, and will be switched if the user switches themes?